# VuGen web-HTTP/HTML load test script debugger stop working

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

when I was replaying my Web app-HTTP/HTML Load testing script, blocked by
"UttStandaloneDebugger has stopped working"
what should I do...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOpiM.png)

Comment: Hi, this error could be caused by many reasons. Could you please open a support ticket?

Comment: thanks, I have recreated my test solution and that error has gone